# Javascript / JQuery comma separated value find last in list and build array

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a list of options in a select field and each one of these has a comma separated list in the value, I need to loop through these and get the last item in the list and build an array to set into some input fields.

I need to do this in reverse as the ',' separated value I am getting is from a web service which will parse either 5 or 6 items of data which build into an address.

I have started on JSFiddle but I am a bit stuck.

http://jsfiddle.net/justinerswell/feDTU/1/

Any help would be great, I know that this is no the best way of processing data but its all I have to work with.

I have reposted this as it warrants it as the question has evolved.

Thanks

Comment: I think we need some more detail of what you want to do with the data.

Comment: Well, the `array.pop()` function will always remove and return the last item in any array. `array[array.length-1]` will do the same without removing it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion the aim is to create a postcode lookup utility so the page with the results will be launched from a parent and so the user will select a result and then click a button and the address fields will be populated.

Comment: Hi Justin. So you just want to get build an array of postcodes? Is that right?

Comment: @Joe not really I am using a c# web app to search a web service for the postcode and return the address. the results are the address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question I assume that you are looking to parse the value from either 5 or 6 comma separated value in your option and then separate them into array and want to do something with them (like putting it somewhere else). Below is the modification of your script that I made. I am not getting the question clearly, but I am assuming this is what you want.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').click(function () {
            var selected = $(this).find(':selected').text();
            var substr = selected.split(',');

            var country = "";
            var postcode = "";
            var county = "";
            var city = "";
            var addthree = "";
            var addtwo = "";
            var addone = "";

            if(substr.length == 5) {
                country = substr[4];
                postcode = substr[3];
                county = substr[2];
                city = substr[1];
                addone = substr[0];
            } else if (substr.length == 6) {
                country = substr[5];
                postcode = substr[4];
                county = substr[3];
                city = substr[2];
                addtwo = substr[1]
                addone = substr[0];
            }

            // do something here with the array
        });
    });
```